# Custom Listview with Image & Detail Image + Text using Volley

Tags: android, json, listview, android-volley

I did this tutorial from androidhive ( http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/) which i want to modify a little bit.
I have a custom json file, something like that:

[ movie: { title: batman, thumbnail: url, detailimage: url } , {....} ]

and now i want to achieve that when user is clicking on one item of the row, the detailimage from the movie will be displayed in a new subactivity!
What is the best way to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Start a new Activity and pass the imageURL as an Intent extra to the new Activity. Start downloading the image from the new Activity. Use an image library such as UniversalImageLoader or Piccaso. Reduces the burden by a huge margin.